# instance variables only visible internally in class

Tags: ios, objective-c

**NOTE:** I am only talking about **.m** file here.

I am confused by these two things, both are said to be the way to declare internal instance variable:

**Way 1:**

```
@interface MyClass ()
 // Declare instance variable which is only visible in this class
@end

@implementation MyClass
...
@end
```

**Way 2:**

```
@implementation MyClass {
   // Declare instance variable which is only visible in this class
}
...
@end
```

What are the differences between these two ways of declaring instance variables?

Answer (score 0):

In terms of functionality, there is no difference.

Declaring the ivars in a class extension -- the `@interface MyClass() {...ivars...}@end` pattern -- does allow you to move the ivar declaration to a header file that could then be used by other classes for direct access for internal-only use, for example.

Answer (score 0):

After the "@interface" line, you can add instance variables within curly braces. That's instance variables, not properties. After the curly braces, or immediately after the "@interface" line if you have no curly braces, you add methods and properties.

So your first comment is wrong. Instance variables can only be added within the curly braces. Properties generate instance variables (usually but not always), but they are not instance variables.

Answer (score 0):

Besides ivar, properties also generate setter and getter method if necessary (according your property attribute). But if you implement the setter and getter synchronously, compiler would not synthesize ivar, since the compiler will assume that you are taking control over the property implementation and won’t synthesize an instance variable automatically.

Answer (score 0):

In `Objective C` the `{ }` it’s the area where you declare instance variables. You can also use access member declaration in that section like `@private` @`public` & `@protected`. When you declares the "ivars" outside the `{}` the variable will be a file-scope variable (kind of static) and it won't be an instance variable of your class.

If you use properties (`@property`) the compiler is smart enough and will create its own ivars with its corresponding setter and getter.

Using a class extension in the implementation file allows you to add ivars or properties (and methods) that are only accessible by the implementation of the class extension. It also allows you to overwrite access of base classes like properties or private methods.